# Jquery Ajax File Uploader Version 2.1 fails on IE 11-

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I just took over a project, that uses [this](http://www.phpletter.com/download_project_version.php?version_id=34) script from http://www.phpletter.com/ for file upload handling.

It works fine on FF, Chrome and Opera, but fails in IE, since Internet Explorer under 11 has no support for it ( I need IE9 and IE10 support ).

**Any Idea how to fix this the fast way without switching to an entirely different script?**

Because that would be painful, since the script is used everywhere on the project :(

Comment: You could detect IE < 11 (with modernizr for example) and fallback to a classic upload solution in that case only. This won't be so nice, but either people change browser, either they accept to have not-so-nice functionalities...

Comment: The problem is, that the rest of the form is also submitted via AJAX, so I can't fall back. I found some scripts, that generate an iframe and then submit, but in order to use them, I need to remake the whole site.

Comment: Well, there's no magic solution. The scripts you talk about are fallback solutions, if you can't use them neither you're stuck. It seems the original developer didn't care about the specs... AJAX upload with no fallback when IE 9 and 10 have to be supported was a very bad idea.